# How to separate known_hosts lines into four parts with stream

Tags: regex, java-8, stream

I'm reading a "known_hosts" file with Java 8 stream.
Here's is an example of a common line:

```
my_host,0.0.0.0 ssh-rsa xxxxxxxx
```

For each line, I want to separate it into 4 parts: (host, ip, key_type, key)

But, I tried to look for a regex in Java and don't really know how it works.

How do I solve this problem?

```
String knownHostsPath = "target/test/known_hosts";
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(knownHostsPath))) {
        stream.forEach(line -> {
            line.split("*");
        }
        );
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if this is what you were looking for using streams to read and parse your file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex `[, ]` for splitting your line as the values in your line are either separated by comma or space. Try your modified Java code using,

```
String knownHostsPath = "target/test/known_hosts";

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(knownHostsPath))) {
    List<String[]> list = stream
            .map(x -> x.split("[, ]")) // use map to split each line into array of strings using [, ] regex which means either space or comma
            .filter(x -> x.length == 4) // use filter to retain only values which have four values after splitting to get rid away of junk lines
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect the string array containing your four (host, ip, keytype, key) values as list

    list.forEach(x -> { // print the values or do whatever
        System.out.println(String.format("Host: %s, IP: %s, KeyType: %s, Key: %s", x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]));
    });
}
```

Prints the following,

```
Host: my_host, IP: 0.0.0.0, KeyType: ssh-rsa, Key: xxxxxxxx
Host: my_host1, IP: 1.2.3.4, KeyType: ssh-rsa1, Key: yyyyyyyy
```

Assuming your file contents were this,

```
my_host,0.0.0.0 ssh-rsa xxxxxxxx
my_host1,1.2.3.4 ssh-rsa1 yyyyyyyy
```

Comment: Glad to help :)